# Is there anyway to authenticate microsoft personal account users with ADAL V1.0 endpoint itself instead of choosing V2.0

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Can we authenticate outlook, hotmail users with adal v1.0 endpoint itself instead of going for msal v2.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication

Can we follow steps mentioned in above article to provide personal account access to web apps in V1.0 endpoint.

Actually I have an azure app service which authenticates work or school accounts using ADAL v1.0 . I got a requirement to authenticate personal account users aswell. Is it possible to do this with ADAL itself instead of choosing MSAL

Comment: Looks more like server administration and provisioning to me. Maybe you can edit the question and bring it back on-topic for the site?

Comment: Actually I have an app service which  authenticates work or school accounts using ADAL v1.0 . I got a requirement to authenticate personal account users aswell. Is it possible to do this with ADAL itself instead of choosing MSAL.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I known, if you authenticate users with ADAL, the account which you use to authenticate must be in the Azure AD tenant. In other words, the account must be a work or school account. So you cannot use ADAL to complete authentication with personal Microsoft accounts. for more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison). Besides, if you want to use personal Microsoft accounts to finish authentication, you need to use [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) or [configure your App Service application to use Microsoft Account login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication).